# Swift: Switch case with multiple patterns cannot bind to variable

Tags: swift, switch-statement

In the official [Swift Programming Language](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Statements.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH33-ID428) guide, it has this to say about switch case:
"...if the case contains multiple patterns that match the control expression, none of those patterns can contain constant or variable bindings."

What does it mean by containing multiple patterns?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It means that case labels with multiple patterns cannot declare variables.

This is allowed:

```
let somePoint = (1, 1)
switch somePoint {
// Case with multiple patterns without binding
case (0, _),
     (_, 0):
    println("(\(somePoint.0), \(somePoint.1)) is on an axis")
default:
    println("(\(somePoint.0), \(somePoint.1)) is not of an axis")
}
```

This is allowed, too:

```
let somePoint = (1, 1)
switch somePoint {
// Case with single patterns with binding
case (0, let y):
    println("(0, \(y)) is on an axis")
case (let x, 0):
    println("(\(x), 0) is on an axis")
default:
    println("(\(somePoint.0), \(somePoint.1)) is not of an axis")
}
```

However, this is prohibited:

```
let somePoint = (1, 1)
switch somePoint {
// Case with multiple patterns that have bindings
case (0, let y),
     (let x, 0):
    println("(\(x), \(y)) is on an axis")
default:
    println("(\(somePoint.0), \(somePoint.1)) is not of an axis")
}
```

The above produces an error:

```
error: 'case' labels with multiple patterns cannot declare variables
```

Comment: Thanks, in what cases do people use multiple pattern (first example)?

Comment: @Boon They do it when they want identical code to be executed for two distinct patterns. In my example you can achieve the same result with a `fallthrough` keyword. However, it is not the same in general, because multiple patterns can share an optional guard, while individual cases with a `fallthrough` would need to repeat the `where` guard.

Comment: What's optional guard? I saw the phrase guard expression (enforced by the use of "where"), but not optional guard.

Comment: @Boon That's the "where" expression. Swift manual calls it a "guard expression". Guard expressions can be omitted, so they are optional.

Comment: Thanks - you mentioned multiple patterns can share optional guard.  How can you share something that's omitted?

Comment: @Boon It's optional because it can be omitted. When it's omitted, it obviously cannot be shared. What I mean is `case (0,_), (_,0) where somePoint.0<2 && somePoint.1<2: println("Point on an axis is in the (2x2) box")` Here, two patterns `(0,_)` and `(_,0)` share a single guard `where somePoint.0<2 && somePoint.1<2`.