# Swift Associative Enum use parameters in fallthrough

Tags: ios, swift, swift3

Is this possible?

```
        switch type {
        case let .dog(say): fallthrough
        case let .cat(say):
            print(say)
        }
```

This is not valid swift enum, but is there a way to do this?
Basically my enum both have the same case actions, but the parameters values will be different.

Answer (score 2):

```
switch type {
case .dog(let say), .cat(let say):
    print(say)
}
```

Comment: Interesting, that did not work with Swift 2. – Here is a similar question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33654074/fallthrough-in-a-switch-case-with-variable-declaration-in-swift  (closed as a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30545503/swift-switch-case-with-multiple-patterns-cannot-bind-to-variable) so this might need a new answer for Swift 3.

Comment: @MartinR It was implemented in Swift 3: https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0043-declare-variables-in-case-labels-with-multiple-patterns.md